# In SQL Server what function or calculation does the % sign perfrom in this statement if @RecCtr % 10000 =0

Tags: sql-server, function, percentage

I tried running @RecCtr % 10000 this by setting different values for @RecCtr

I can see that if the value is 250000  then @RecCtr % 10000 will return zero and if i set the value of  @RecCtr to 250111 for example, '@RecCtr % 10000' will return 111, can someone please shed some light on what does % do in this case. Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It is a remainder operation (modulus).

So if you take 
10 / 2 = 5 with remainder 0, your answer is 0

10%2=0

If you take 11 / 2 = 5 with remainder 1 your answer is 2

12%2=1

If we try 13/5 = 2 with remainder of 3, thus the answer would be 3

Comment: Thanks for explaining Nikki, much appreciated.